# Podspec debug/release `vendored_framework` variants

Tags: ios, flutter, cocoapods, podspec

I have a flutter plugin (let's say it's named `plugin`) that needs to have a separate debug build (say `debug/foo.framework`) and a release build (`release/foo.framework`) and they should be used in the respective app builds. Is there a way to do this?

```
Pod::Spec.new do |s|
  ...
  s.xcconfig = { 'OTHER_LDFLAGS' => '-framework foo' }
  s.vendored_frameworks = 'foo.framework'
end
```

What I'd want, conceptually, is something like this (should work for `dependency`, but doesn't for `vendored_framework` - says `file: undefined method 'vendored_frameworks'`)

```
Pod::Spec.new do |s|
  ...
  s.xcconfig = { 'OTHER_LDFLAGS' => '-framework foo' }
  s.vendored_frameworks 'debug/foo.framework', :configurations => ['Debug']
  s.vendored_frameworks 'release/foo.framework', :configurations => ['Release']
```

I've also tried this, but it fails with circular dependency:

```
Pod::Spec.new do |s|
  s.name     = 'plugin'
  ...
  s.xcconfig = { 'OTHER_LDFLAGS' => '-framework foo' }

  s.subspec 'debug' do |cs|
    cs.vendored_frameworks = 'debug/foo.framework'
  end
  s.subspec 'release' do |cs|
    cs.vendored_frameworks = 'release/foo.framework'
  end

  s.default_subspecs = :none
  s.dependency 'plugin/debug', :configurations => ['Debug']
  s.dependency 'plugin/release', :configurations => ['Release']
end
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue (when dealing with React-Native) and ended up dividing the plugin in to 3 Pods.

**my-plugin:**

```
Pod::Spec.new do |s|
  s.name         = "my-plugin"
  s.dependency "my-lib-debug", :configurations => ['Debug']
  s.dependency "my-lib-release", :configurations => ['Release']
end
```

**my-lib-debug:**

```
Pod::Spec.new do |s|
  s.name         = "my-lib-debug"
  s.ios.vendored_framework = 'ios/dependencies/debug/my-lib.xcframework'
end
```

**my-lib-release:**

```
Pod::Spec.new do |s|
  s.name         = "my-lib-release"
  s.ios.vendored_framework = 'ios/dependencies/release/my-lib.xcframework'
end
```

**Application Podfile:**

```
  pod 'my-plugin', :path => 'path/to/my-plugin'
  pod 'my-lib-debug', :path => 'path/to/my-lib-debug', :configurations => ['Debug']
  pod 'my-lib-release', :path => 'path/to/my-lib-release', :configurations => ['Release']
```